# getting response code 401 while sending message to the gcm server using the browser key

Tags: android, apache

I have used my browser key here to send message to gcm server. Also tried it with server key but still getting same error. I also tried doing authentication using `defaulthttpclient` with username and password but didn't get any result.

here is the code of my application server:

```
package com.example.gcmserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthState;
import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
        client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {


    @Override
    public void process(HttpRequest arg0, HttpContext context)
            throws HttpException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          AuthState state = (AuthState) context.getAttribute(ClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);
             if (state.getAuthScheme() == null) {
                 BasicScheme scheme = new BasicScheme();
                 CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = (CredentialsProvider) context.getAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER);
                 Credentials credentials = credentialsProvider.getCredentials(AuthScope.ANY);
                 if (credentials == null) {
                     throw new HttpException();
                 }
                 state.setAuthScope(AuthScope.ANY);
                 state.setAuthScheme(scheme);
                 state.setCredentials(credentials);
    }}
 }, 0); 





        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);


          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

          List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data.registration id","APA91bGChJVdx2L1AUIJEVIBBVEkxEAk6zixj5V-L--fDGXudvrtl5gSQDgAP4iUJoMRq57sLSpGtsSQ5gnprX4McOPq7WxglKeQyTmaysVb0r-adOZ4tTjWG2MYwVEayFKy9Rwf1mloVt2jb-_izUdN-SfKvlpUpEYXNNT1987tYASKCcam16g"));

          urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data.title", "e-pass application"));
          urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data.message", "Your code is 13133"));


          httppost.setHeader("Authorization",
                  "key=AIzaSyDANlJHGPmzo1so_yyqkYZO7LSrQpnR7mk");
          httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

          post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters, "UTF-8"));

          HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
          System.out.println("Response Code : " 
                      + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

          StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
          String line = "";
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              result.append(line);
          }
}
}

I have also add the httpclient, httpcore jar files in build path but still getting error.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons are there of response code 401 like mistake in your project ID. YO u might have forgotten ton enable cloud messaging service in api console.

You can have more detail at [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html)  :)

Answer (score 0):

Fire base Push notification code in java

```
private boolean sendFCMNotification(String fcmKey,JSONObject jsonDataObject){         
        try {
            String serverKey = "AAAAZmvesa8:APA91bHdK";
            String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
            HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("to",fcmKey);
            json.put("time_to_live",100);
            //set data object
            json.put("data",jsonDataObject);
            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            httppost.setEntity(stringEntity);
            log.info("request string: "+json.toString());
            httppost.setHeader("Authorization","key="+serverKey);
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            //Execute and get the response.
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                try {
                    // do something useful
                    String responseStr = streamToString(inputStream);
                    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
                    if(responseObject.getInt("success")>0) {
                        log.info("notification sent successful: ");
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        log.info("notification sent fail: ");
                        return false;
                    }
                } finally {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            log.info("msg: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    private String streamToString(InputStream inputStream){
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String string = "";
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                result.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            string = result.toString("UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return string;
    }
```